# Automatically spread identity when persisting @OneToMany field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

I am developing twig fiddle, the js/sql/php-fiddle equivalent for [Twig language](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). We can add several templates to render a result, and I have the following entities:

```
class Fiddle
{

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection[FiddleTemplate]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FiddleTemplate", mappedBy="fiddle", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $templates;

    // ...

}

class FiddleTemplate
{

    /**
     * @var Fiddle
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Fiddle", inversedBy="templates")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fiddle_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $fiddle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string", length=64)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    protected $filename = 'main.twig';

    // ...
}
```

As you can imagine, I can add / remove templates from UI.

Fiddle's id takes part of the Fiddle entity, so if I want to persist templates for the first time, I first need to persist the fiddle. I do it using a Doctrine event suscriber (see rev history if interested). But if I try to add a template to an already-existing fiddle and save, I come up with the following exception:

> Entity of type Fuz\AppBundle\Entity\FiddleTemplate is missing an
>   assigned ID for field 'fiddle'. The identifier generation strategy for
>   this entity requires the ID field to be populated before
>   EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated
>   identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping
>   accordingly.

Sounds logic enough, as I need to spread the Fiddle's instance to the template before persisting.

But I did not found any Doctrine event fired on the Fiddle entity, `preUpdate` is not called even if `templates` takes part of the entity, because it does not require any update. Only a `pre/postPersist` event is fired on the FiddleTemplate entity, but it does not help that much.

I currently do something quite ugly IMHO: before persisting, I call a `spreadFiddle` on my entity:

```
$fiddle->spreadFiddle();
$this->em->persist($fiddle);
$this->em->flush();
```

The method looks like:

```
public function spreadFiddle()
{
    foreach ($this->templates as $template)
    {
        $template->setFiddle($this);
    }
}
```

Here my question come:

> Is there a better way (using events or annotations) to spread the Fiddle entity to all templates?

Comment: Isn't it better to make `Fiddle::addTemplate($template)` method, which will add template to collection (`$this->templates->add($template)`) and set link to self (`$template->setFiddle($this)`). AFAIK, it is recommended way if Fiddle is an aggregation root of your model.

Comment: Hum that's not that easy in fact, because my form collection is automatically filled by Symfony2, and my `$fiddle->setTemplates()` looks not to be called after form validation.

Comment: remove `setTemplates`, use `addTemplate` and `removeTemplate` instead. It's an easier way for form collections.

Comment: Nice. And we should also set `'by_reference' => false` in the form type so those methods are being called. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it better to make `Fiddle::addTemplate($template)` method, which will add template to collection (`$this->templates->add($template)`) and set link to self (`$template->setFiddle($this)`). AFAIK, it is recommended way if Fiddle is an aggregation root of your model.